# How can I create a record from different controllers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

**The Problem:**

I have a Token model that can have a category (authentication, refresh, confirmation, reset_password). I need to be able to create tokens from the following controller actions:

1. registrations#post - When the user signs up, I need to create a confirmation token to be used in the welcome email. For Example:

   ```
   # POST /users => registrations#create
   def create
       @user = User.new(create_user_params)

       if @user.save
           # create confirmation token here. something like Token.create(category: "confirmation")
           Api::V1::UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user.id).deliver_later
           render json: @user, status: :created
       else
           render json: { errors: @user.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity
       end
   end
   ```
2. confirmations#post - When the user requests authorization to access an API, I need to create an authentication token / refresh token pair.
3. passwords#post - When the user requests a forgot password email, I need to create a reset_password token.

**A few additional notes:**

- There is some custom logic to be done depending on the category.
- The relationship between User and Token is has_many.

**The Question:**

Is there a way I could pass the category to the Token controller's create action from one of these other controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to create controller action that calls another controller action. This is possible, but will give you a lot of problems (as both will try to render). The only really acceptable way to jump from one controller action to another is via `redirect_to`, and that is not going to solve the problems you described.

In an MVC framework (such as rails), what you're going to want to do is move the reused parts of the `token#create` action into the token *model*, and then reference this from `token#create`, `registrations#post`, `confirmations#post`, and `passwords#post`. This could be a method like `Token.define_token( my_params )`, or simply the existing `Token.create()` method.

Model behaviour such as what you described belongs in the Model. The Controller should simply be calling this, as the Controller's purpose is generally to set up the View.

**References:**

- [Common Mistake #1](http://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/top-10-mistakes-that-rails-programmers-make)
- [Fat Model, Skinny Controller](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-ruby-on-rails-best-practices/)

Answer (score 0):

Passing the category to the Token's controller is unnecessary. Just like ConnorCMcKee said, controller calling another controller method is going to make your life miserably and not how it should be done in a MVC framework. You should just create the token right in your user's controller like the example you wrote yourself.

```
def create
   @user = User.new(create_user_params)

   if @user.save
    @user.tokens.create(category: "confirmation")
    render json: @user, status: :created
   else
    render json: { errors: @user.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity
   end
end
```

And if you want to deliver it later you can use a background job gem to do that for you.